# Firebase Remote Config A/B Test draft does not provide values on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

I have created an AB Test on Firebase(not Published yet) and added token of a test device.
But the value is not coming for the provided key.

As AB testing is in Beta, so is it a bug on Firebase side that it doesn't work on test devices?

```
let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: 0) { status, _ in
        if status == RemoteConfigFetchStatus.success {
            remoteConfig.activateFetched()
            let ab_test_value = remoteConfig.configValue(forKey: "ab_test_key").stringValue
            print(ab_test_value)
 }}
```

The ab_test_value is coming as empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this may your variable is deallocated when response come

```
var remoteConfig:FIRRemoteConfig?
```

///

```
var expirationDuration = 43200;
// If in developer mode cacheExpiration is set to 0 so each fetch will retrieve values from
// the server.
if (remoteConfig?.configSettings.isDeveloperModeEnabled)!
{
     expirationDuration = 0;
}


self.remoteConfig?.fetch(withExpirationDuration: TimeInterval(expirationDuration))
{
    (status, error) -> Void in
    if status == .success
    {
        print("Config fetched!")
         self.remoteConfig?.activateFetched()
    }
    else
    {
        print("Config not fetched")
        print("Error \(error!.localizedDescription)")

       // return
    }

    self.displayWelcome()

    }

}
```

Comment: It works only when experiment is published and not on draft experiments

Comment: may be u're missing something it works with me even in debug mode make sure  **  FIRApp.configure() ** is in top of didFinishLaunching